# Go unmarshal JSON with unknown field name but known struct

Tags: json, go, traefik

I retrieve a acme.json from [traefik tls](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/) where traefik stores ssl/tls certificate information.

Now I want to unmarshal with golang the acme.json into my go struct "Traefik". But I don't know how to handle dynamic/unknown json field names because `certificateresolver1` and `certificateresolver2` are names I don't know at compile time. These names should be dynamic configured in go.

I know the structure of the json (it is always the same) but not know the field name of the certificateresolver.

Does anyone know the best way to do this?

#### Traefik acme.json

```json
{
  "certificateresolver1": {
    "Account": {
      "Email": "email@example.com",
      "Registration": {
        "body": {
          "status": "valid",
          "contact": [
            "mailto:email@example.com"
          ]
        },
        "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/124448363"
      },
      "PrivateKey": "PRIVATEKEY",
      "KeyType": "4096"
    },
    "Certificates": [
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "example.com",
          "sans": [
            "test.example.com"
          ]
        },
        "certificate": "CERTIFICATE",
        "key": "KEY",
        "Store": "default"
      },
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "example.org"
        },
        "certificate": "CERTIFICATE",
        "key": "KEY",
        "Store": "default"
      }
    ]
  },
  "certificateresolver2": {
    "Account": {
      "Email": "email@example.com",
      "Registration": {
        "body": {
          "status": "valid",
          "contact": [
            "mailto:email@example.com"
          ]
        },
        "uri": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/126945414"
      },
      "PrivateKey": "PRIVATEKEY",
      "KeyType": "4096"
    },
    "Certificates": [
      {
        "domain": {
          "main": "example.net"
        },
        "certificate": "CERTIFICATE",
        "key": "KEY",
        "Store": "default"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Go struct for acme.json

```golang
type Traefik struct {
    Provider []struct {
        Account struct {
            Email        string `json:"Email"`
            Registration struct {
                Body struct {
                    Status  string   `json:"status"`
                    Contact []string `json:"contact"`
                } `json:"body"`
                URI string `json:"uri"`
            } `json:"Registration"`
            PrivateKey string `json:"PrivateKey"`
            KeyType    string `json:"KeyType"`
        } `json:"Account"`
        Certificates []struct {
            Domain struct {
                Main string   `json:"main"`
                Sans []string `json:"sans"`
            } `json:"domain"`
            Certificate string `json:"certificate"`
            Key         string `json:"key"`
            Store       string `json:"Store"`
        } `json:"Certificates"`
    } `json:"certificateresolver"` <-- What to write there? It should fit for certificateresolver1 and certificateresolver2
}
```

Comment: If you don't know the field name, use a map.

Comment: you can use fatih struct and use omitempty tag https://github.com/fatih/structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this will help you:

```golang
type ProviderMdl map[string]Provider

type Provider struct {
    Account struct {
        Email        string `json:"Email"`
        Registration struct {
            Body struct {
                Status  string   `json:"status"`
                Contact []string `json:"contact"`
            } `json:"body"`
            URI string `json:"uri"`
        } `json:"Registration"`
        PrivateKey string `json:"PrivateKey"`
        KeyType    string `json:"KeyType"`
    } `json:"Account"`
    Certificates []struct {
        Domain struct {
            Main string   `json:"main"`
            Sans []string `json:"sans"`
        } `json:"domain"`
        Certificate string `json:"certificate"`
        Key         string `json:"key"`
        Store       string `json:"Store"`
    } `json:"Certificates"`
}
```

So you could work with this data in this way:

```golang
    bres := new(ProviderMdl)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, bres); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    // fmt.Printf("%+v - \n", bres)

    for key, value := range *bres {
        fmt.Printf("%v - %v\n", key, value)
    }
```

Full example [here](https://play.golang.com/p/CaISz4jr3uB)